# AWS S3, speed and server load

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I Hope this question is the right sort (If not, instead of just down-voting could someone point me to where I can get this answered).

I am trying to be a forward thinker and tackle a problem before it arises.

## Scenario

I have a small mailing list website where every week I post links to things web related that I like and find useful.

There is a latest article page which shows everything that I added into the database that month. At the moment there are 6 sections; Intro, News, Design, Development, Twitter, Q&A. The website shows these like so:

> **Section**
>
> - Check database for all entries that match {Month} && {Section}
> - Foreach {Section} return {Title} {Desc} {Link}

I usually have about 3 links per section. This also means **6** db requests per page view.

## Concerns

- When/if the site gains in popularity, let's say I get a 5k visitor spike thats 30,000 db requests which I don't think my server host will either like nor look the other way, probably ending up with me being charged a lot and my site crashing.

## Question

Which one of these solutions do you think will be the wisest in terms of speed and lowering server resources with requests:

- 1) Use PHP to make one db request getting all the entries, adding them into an array and then lopping through the array to generate the sections
- 2) Use a cron to generate all the months entries, make them into a JSON file and parse that JSON on page load, Host on my server
- 3) Use a cron to generate all the months entries, make them into a JSON file and parse that JSON on page load, Host them on AWS S3
- 4) Use a cron to generate all the entries as separate text files, for example february-2016-intro-one.txt and save that on S3, then on the latest article page get the text files for each one and parse them

## Discussion

- If you have any other ideas, I would be happy to hear them :)

Thanks for your patience with reading this, Looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Don't worry, be happy.  Really.

Comment: Thanks, I'm always happy. Same to you .

Answer (score 2):

> CloudFront is a web service that speeds up distribution of your static and dynamic web content, for example, .html, .css, .php, and image files, to end users.

My advice would be to stick with the cron job and save the JSON file to S3, but also use CloudFront to host the file from your S3 bucket. Though hosting from your server my seem fastest, because it is located in only 1 place or region, speed will vary depending on where people access it from. If a user is viewing your site from far away then they will have a slower load time than someone who is closer.

With CloudFront, your file(s) are distributed ***and*** cached on Amazon's 50+ edge locations around the world, giving you the fastest and most reliable delivery times.

Also, in the future if you want your users to see new content as soon as it is update, take a look into Lambda. It runs code in response to events from other AWS services. So whenever your database is updated (if it's DynamoDB or RDS) you can automatically generate a new JSON file and save it to S3. It will still continue to be distributed by CloudFront once you've gotten that connection set up.

More information about CloudFront [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html)

More information about Lambda [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Build a cache!**

When you do one of these queries, store the result in a cache together with the current time. When you next go to do one of these queries, check the cache -- if it's within a desired timeframe (eg 10 hours?), just use the stored results; if the time has expired, do another query and store the results again.

This way, you'll only ever do such a complex query once per time period.

As to making the cache -- it could be something as simple as storing the result in file, but it would work better keeping it in memory (global variable?). I'm not a PHP person, but there seems to be an `apc_store()` command.